# GWT 2.4 Drag and Drop and IE9

Tags: gwt2

I have drag and drop working on a prototype application and seems to work ok except on IE9.

there are inconsistencies between browsers and operating systems in image that is dragged but we can handle that for now

but the real issue is that IE9 doesn't drag correctly.  The same effect occurs with the sample app http://gwt-cloudtasks.appspot.com/ 
IE9 doesn't allow dragging unless you first select some text in the drag source.  For instance in the cloudtasks app if you select text in the "Call mom" template you can then drag it in IE9.  I thought that maybe I could hack a solution for now by autoselecting text in my source object on mouse down but no one like the hack.

Any ideas?